# Creating Database in ActionScript

Tags: xml, database, actionscript-3

I am beginner of AS3 and I want to make a xml file retiring and saving the data through as3 program without using PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Shared Objects](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/SharedObject.html). They act like persistent local storage--a "flash cookie."